# Get a single value from document

Tags: couchdb

Is there a possibility in CouchDB to retrieve a single value from a document? For example, I have a document with 10000 keys like this:

```
{
   "_id": "8098091cc795acde43cd45335373cc92",
   "_rev": "2-6d2e0ac43618388cc958b91e5015bba5",
   "1":"some value",
   "2":"another value",
   ...
   "10000":"last value"
}
```

and I don't want to parse the whole document each time but just want to get a value of key "2". Is this possible?

**EDIT:**

Of course, before asking this question I looked through the docs and googled around this but haven't found such possibility. But I'm wondering why this is not possible? In my understanding it is not too much difference between view and document since both of them are sets of key-value pairs, but it is possible to get single value from view using `?key=...` in the query string and not possible to do the same for document. Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a [CouchDB show function](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List#Showing_Documents) to process a document on the server and send arbitrary data to the client. Show functions can do simple things like extracting a single value from the document; or they can convert to a completely different content-type such as XML.

For example:

- In database `db`
- which has design document `_design/example` with show function `one_field`
- you want to fetch document with ID `doc_id`
- but only retrieve the field `some_field` which has a value `"I am the some_field value!"`

That query would be:

```
GET /db/_design/example/_show/one_field/doc_id?name=some_field
```

The show function would look like this:

```
function(doc, req) {
  // _show function to extract one field

  var field_name = req.query.name; // Set to e.g. "some_field"
  var field_value = doc[field_name];

  return { "code": 200   // HTTP status code
         , "headers":    // Response headers
           { "content-type": "text/plain" }
         , body: field_value
         };
}
```

The design document would look like this:

```
{ "_id": "_design/example"
, "shows":
  { "one_field": ... } // Paste the above function as a string.
}
```

CouchDB will return

```
HTTP 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 26

I am the some_field value!
```

Comment: Thank you! It does exactly what I need and even more.

Comment: @Vader You're welcome. I edited the answer to correct a minor mistake in the URL (forgot to include the document ID in the path).

Comment: can use the same technique with a variable to get just one record ?

Comment: @stackdave I think the answer is yes. To me, a "record" is what CouchDB calls a "document." In my opinion, the best way to use CouchDB is to try to use show and list functions as little as possible. Just fetch the document, or the view rows, etc. and work through them with your own program. (Although the functions are useful in some cases, such as to reduce the data on the wire.)

Comment: it's not clear for me /one_field/ how it's work, on the list or in function, is not more simple work direct trought the url by id, without nano? fetch all de documents and reduce it just for one record is not expensive for the server?

Answer (score 1):

No. CouchDB is a document oriented DB, so it doesn't support more granular access to the data beyond the overall document itself.

It gives you fine grained indexing, but not actual access.

Comment: Ok. It is document oriented... But why it is possible to get value by key from view and not possible from document? Is there too much difference between them? In my understanding they are both key-value storages.

Comment: @Will is fundamentally correct. My answer about `_show` functions is CouchDB's syntax sugar for the HTTP API. The `_show` functions do the same thing a client would do: fetch an entire document and discard most of it. Indeed, they must be pure functions to be deterministic for a given document. On the other hand, it sure does *feel* like a single-value query. `_update` functions are even nicer!